# OnPostRequestHandlerExecute event is not getting fired in SharePoint 2010 application's Global.asax file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, global-asax

We want to capture current user's employee id, name, url of SharePoint 2010 site.
We are inserting captured data in database.
To get this we have written code in below event of Global.asax file -

```
void OnPostRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs a)
{
//code
}
```

The same code is running in SharePoint 2007 application's Global.asax file but the same code is not getting fired in SharePoint 2010 application's Global.asax file.
Please guide me if anything needs to be enable to get this event triggered.How can I debug?
 Thanks for the time..

Answer (score 0):

I implemented similar functionality and I have created class implementing IHttpModule and register it in web.config (configuration/system.webServer/modules) instead of using global.asax. It's recommended way for SharePoint 2010.

You can optionally wrap it in feature and use SPWebConfigModification within feature receiver. Then you can turn it on or of by activating or deactivating feature.

Comment: Thanks Mazin for your inputs..do you have any link for referance for the same and out of curiosity I am asking if anyone wants to use global.asax in SharePoint 2010 then what steps needs to be done.

Comment: Take a look on this Codeplex project https://go.codeplex.com/ It does SharePoint request redirecting but the way of hooking and handling user requests is clear in source codes